# Oracle error SP2-0734 on insert

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm using sqlplus directly on the server Oracle version 10.2.0.5

I've a problem Loading data with a simple script like this on

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ",.";
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
@TEST_DATA_TABLE.sql
commit;
```

File TEST_DATA_TABLE.sql

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into test ( ID_TEST, .... ) values ('1',....);
Insert into test ( ID_TEST, .... ) values ('2',....);
...
Insert into test ( ID_TEST, .... ) values ('10',...,.... 'jlkjlkdjs');
...
Insert into test ( ID_TEST, .... ) values ('500000',....);
...
```

i have the following error exemple for all the lines too long :
    SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "jlkj ......." - rest of line ignored.
It's OK for the other lines

The limit seems to arround 255 caracters on the same line !
I tried directly in sqlplus copy/paste for line with error, it's ok if i cut the line on multiple lines...

I'm looking for a solution better than creating a shell to slip all the long line.

thks

Answer (score 0):

It's normal regarding the documentation :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/apa.htm

to insert more data, i did this :

```
for file in *DATA*.sql
do
  wc -l  ${file}
  sed 's/ values / values\n /g' $file > IMPORT/$file
  dos2unix  IMPORT/"$file" IMPORT/"$file"
  cat IMPORT/"$file" | awk 'length($0) > 240' | wc -l
done
```

And i hope to have time to work on a better solution